# "Authority mismatch on settings vs. signin state" with OIDC Client when trying to grant access between 2 client Applications

Tags: identityserver4, openid-connect, openid, openid-client-js

We have two .net core with angular applications where we have used Openid server and client
https://localhost:80 : Parent Application
https://localhost:85 : Child Application

We want to authenticate the child application within the parent application.
In the angular end, we used oidc-client and updated the UserManager dynamically inside the child application.

The flow we are trying to achieve is

**Login Page child application (https://localhost:85) -> Click Login -> it redirects to parent app Login Page (https://localhost) -> entering credentials and After successful signing in the redirection URL will be (https://localhost:85) and it will grant access to that child application.**

While redirecting to the child application by redirect URL after login  it throws the below error  "Authority mismatch on settings vs. signin state"
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Can someone help me with the flow of authentication of multiple client applications via openid client ?

```
 Error: authority mismatch on settings vs. signin state
at t [as _processSigninParams] (oidc-client.min.js:1:57198)
at t [as validateSigninResponse] oidc-client.min.js:1:55646)
at oidc-client.min. js:1:27449 at
ZoneDelegate. invoke (zone, js:372÷26) at Object.onInvoke (core.mjs:26356:33) at
ZoneDelegate. invoke (zone. js:371:52)
at Zone.run (zone. js:134:43)
at zone. js:1275:36 at
ZoneDelegate. invokeTask (zone. js:496:31)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mijs:26343:33)
```

Initially, the child application will have the below config

```
 this.ChildAppConfig = {
  authority: 'https://localhost',
  client_id: 'child-spa',
  redirect_uri: `https://localhost/signin-callback`,
  scope: 'profile openid offline_access',
  response_type: 'code', 
  post_logout_redirect_uri: `https://localhost/signout-callback`,
  silent_redirect_uri: `https://localhost/silent-renew`,
  automaticSilentRenew: false,  
  revokeAccessTokenOnSignout: true,
  accessTokenExpiringNotificationTime: 60,
};
```

When I want to grant access to a child application via a parent application I will redirect it to the parent application, where the parent application will have the below config, and once authenticated it should redirect back to the child application

```
 grantAccessConfig = {
      authority: 'https://localhost:85',
      client_id: 'spa',
      redirect_uri: `https://localhost/signin-callback`,
      scope: 'profile openid offline_access',
      response_type: 'code', 
      post_logout_redirect_uri: `https://localhost/signout-callback`,
      silent_redirect_uri: `https://localhost/silent-renew`,
      automaticSilentRenew: false,  
      revokeAccessTokenOnSignout: true,
      accessTokenExpiringNotificationTime: 60,
    };
```

Comment: could you put your both configs of your client app and identity-server

Comment: im sorry i confused. am i right? 1- login with clientid of 'child-spa'(this login page is identity server login page itself)  2- the identity server authenticated and generate the token based on 'child-spa' client id 3- then you want to redirect to parent app which has client id 'spa' but your token from previous login set to client id 'child-spa' ? (if true this seems a problem i guess) and please give the port on your redirects. all is localhost.  is localhost:85 the identity server? also in one config authority is set to localhost:85 another to localhost only?

Comment: Initially, the Login Page will have the client Id of the Child App, but while clicking login I will redirect to the parent application ( its client id is different ). When the user logins in a parent application take the token and pass it to the child application via redirect URL, this is where the error displays.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i had this error before with Reactjs oidc-react and .net backend. the problem was that the configuration defined in SigninCallBack.js(here i init the storage and redirect) was not same as the configuration defined in identity server. this config was from the test app that throws that error

```
import React from 'react'
import { WebStorageStateStore } from 'oidc-client-ts';
import { UserManager } from 'oidc-react';

    const SigninCallBack = () => {
        var config = {
            userStore: new WebStorageStateStore({store: window.localStorage}),
            authority: "https://localhost:9001/",
            client_id: "myappid",
            redirect_uri: "https://localhost:3000/signincallback",
            client_secret: "thesecretkey_but_i_used_PKCE",
            response_type: "code",
            scope:"openid profile someApi",
            post_logout_redirect_uri : "https://localhost:3000/signout-callback-oidc",
            loadUserInfo: true
            };
     
        
    
        var userManager = new UserManager(config);
    
        userManager.signinCallback().then(res => {
            
            window.location.href = '/';
        });
    }
     
    export default SigninCallBack;
```

and mine was the client url which here i was defined with http but in the identityserver config i defined it with https. however it could be any of them such as response type ,client Id etc.

Comment: Hi, @Rouzbeh thanks for the reply. Yes, both are different , since I am trying to grant access to the child application using the parent application I have updated the User Manager dynamically in my child application. 

I have updated the question FYR